# How do I add all special characters without typing them all out in this regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, special-characters

I'm very new to regex and was wondering if there was a quick way for me to include all the special characters in this regexp without tediously typing them all out?

```
  # Need 1 char of A-Z, a-z, 0-9, special character and 12 characters min
  config.password_regex = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!"'@#$&* £])(?=.{12,})/
```

Comment: something like copy/paste?

Comment: you can use `\W` ?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: I guess more of a character class, ie. `[symbol1-symbol2]`.

Comment: What do you mean by *all the special characters*?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub I meant like !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ and I assume \W would let me do this as I want special characters as password req without having to escape every other char that isn't an issue.

Comment: You may use `/\A(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[[:punct:]]).{12,}\z/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is also a very valid solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closer you can get without having issues with new lines in a password is:

```
[^\w\s]
```

which means *not a whitespace nor a char in the range a-z nor a digit*